# Ошибка 500 на локальном серве и хосте

Tags: php

Пытаюсь настроить форму отправки данных на почту на сайте. Кучу вариантов пробовал, везде ошибка 500!. Я вообще не соображаю в PHP, поэтому не могу понять где беда.
Помогите хоть куда смотреть. Даже версию PHP менял.
вот код php

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require "PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
    require "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
        

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $email_template = "template_mail.html";

    $body = file_get_contents($email_template);
    $body = str_replace('%name%', $name, $body);
    $body = str_replace('%email%', $email, $body);
    $body = str_replace('%phone%', $phone, $body);
    $body = str_replace('%message%', $message, $body);

    $mail->addAddress("tomdelonge1900@gmail.com");   // Здесь введите Email, куда отправлять
    $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->Subject = "[Заявка с формы]";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $message = "Ошибка отправки";
    } else {
        $message = "Данные отправлены!";
    }
    
    $response = ["message" => $message];

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Посмотреть ошибку в логах религия не позволяет?)

Comment: Как минимум ошибки смотрят в логах. Остальное по ссылке выше

Comment: Логи с хоста я взял. Указано 14:44:07 vh372 apache_error[75872]. Только проблема в том, что мне это ни о чем не сказало, да и нагуглить не получилось. я учиться то начал неделю назад, так что это все такой лес темный, что хоть вешайся.

Comment: не там смотрите. apache_error[75872] никому не говорит ни о чём. там есть внутри конкретное описание проблемы